# Attempt at solution for continuity of xsin(1/x) on R (piecewise)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm trying to prove that the piecewise function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as:

\begin{cases} 
      x\sin{\frac{1}{x}} & x\neq 0 \\
      \
      0 & x=0 
   \end{cases}

I've seen proofs using the difference of sines law (for an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof), but I want to make a proof without it! Here's my attempt:

---

I begin by defining two new piecewise functions, $h$ and $g$ defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
g(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        x & x \neq 0\\
        0 & x =0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
h(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        \sin{\frac{1}{x}} & x \neq0\\
        1 & x =0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Clearly, $f$ is the product of these two functions and showing that both $g$ and $h$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ will suffice to prove that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, $g(x)$ can be simplified to the monomial $x$, in which I am able to cite a past proof (which is fine for my purposes). The problem arrises when proving the continuity of $h(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$. If I were to prove this as is, I would need to employ an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof to formalize it which leads me back to using the difference of sines. However, $h(x)$ is a composition of two functions, notably the rational function and the sine function, and so my next step would be to prove that both of these functions are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, allowing me to prove $h(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure if I'm jumping down a rabbit hole to avoid using this sine property, but any hint on how to proceed (or if this is far more complicated for nothing) is much appreciated!

Comment: If you try to draw the graph of h near zero it's pretty obvious that it isn't continuous. As x goes to 0, 1/x goes to infinity. But we know that sin oscillates infinitely many times in the neighbourhood of infinity! so h has to oscillate super fast in the neighbourhood of zero. And if it oscillates super fast then it means that it doesn't converge to a limit, and thus isn't continuous.

Comment: As a proof that h isn't continuous at 0 you can exhibit three sequences (x_n) and (y_n) and (z_n) such that both (x_n) and (y_n) and (z_n) converge to zero, but h(x_n) = -1 and h(y_n) = +1 and h(z_n) = 0 for all n (actually, exhibiting two sequences with different limits would be enough, but you can exhibit these three to show your understanding of what h looks like). If h were continuous at zero then we should have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} h(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} h(y_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} h(z_n) = \lim_{x \to 0} h(x) = h(0)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with this approach is that $h$ is *not* continuous at $x=0$.

A correct proof  uses cases. When $x \ne 0$ you have a product of continuous functions. At $x=0$ it's not hard to find a $\delta$ for any given $\epsilon$.

If you want to hide the $\epsilon - \delta$ argument you can use the squeeze theorem with $x$ and $-x$ at the origin.

Comment: ah I see. I knew I was missing something! Squeeze theorem seems like a no brainer for this problem at 0, whereas elsewhere the product of continuous functions still holds as you said. Thank you!